# Changing bibliography style for a certain bibtex entry

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to write the bibliography of my thesis by following the document:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Masters/Doctoral Thesis 
% LaTeX Template
% Version 2.3 (25/3/16)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Version 2.x major modifications by:
% Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
%
% This template is based on a template by:
% Steve Gunn (http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/srg/softwaretools/document/templates/)
% Sunil Patel (http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/thesis-template/)
%
% Template license:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

The problem I am currently facing is that when I store a "miscellaneous" entry for my bibtex, its title results written in the outcoming pdf file in italic. Unfortunately according to the standards of my university I cannot use italics style for those kind of miscellaneous documents. Therefore I would like to find out how to change the style for those sources.

Comment: Which bibliography style do you use at present? Is it downloadable from somewhere on the 'Net?

Comment: @Mico **\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric,natbib=true,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}** hope this can help!

Comment: Please consider adding proper [minimal working examples (check the link, please)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) in the future. Your question seems quite clear, but there is always a risk that a solution will not work for you because some of the settings you have interfere with it. We can only make sure a solution really works for you if we can test it with your setup.

Comment: If you are using the template unmodified, you can just add a link to the question, no need for the comment block. That comentblock is quite useless if you don't know where to look for the rest.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{citetitle}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
```

to get quotation marks for titles of `@misc` entries.